# How can I enable MySQL's slow query log without restarting MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I followed the instructions here: http://crazytoon.com/2007/07/23/mysql-changing-runtime-variables-with-out-restarting-mysql-server/ but that seems to only set the threshold.

Do I need to do anything else like set the filepath?

According to MySQL's docs

```
If no file_name value is given for --log-slow-queries, the default name is 
host_name-slow.log. The server creates the file in the data directory unless 
an absolute path name is given to specify a different directory.
```

Running

```
SHOW VARIABLES
```

doesn't indicate any log file path and I don't see any slow query log file on my server...

**EDIT**

Looks like I'm using server version 5.0.77, so I needed to do:

```
SET GLOBAL log_slow_queries = 1;
```

but I get: ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'log_slow_queries' is a read only variable

I assume I'm going to need to restart the server and have log_slow_queries set in my config?

Comment: Why don't you test that on a development box ?

Comment: The answer to this question is version-dependent.  Later versions are more flexible, obviating the need for the question.

Answer (score 96):

Try `SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';` and perhaps `FLUSH LOGS;`

This assumes you are using MySQL 5.1 or later. If you are using an earlier version, you'll need to restart the server. This is documented in the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html). You can configure the log either in the config file or on the command line.

Comment: FLUSH SLOW LOGS is available in 5.5!

Comment: Also worked for me on 10.0.36-MariaDB. `SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'OFF';` works as expected, as well. `FLUSH LOGS` was not necessary in either case.

Comment: `FLUSH LOGS;` was the solution, thank you!

Answer (score 28):

For slow queries on version < 5.1, the following configuration worked for me:

```
log_slow_queries=/var/log/mysql/slow-query.log
long_query_time=20
log_queries_not_using_indexes=YES
```

Also note to place it under `[mysqld]` part of the config file and restart `mysqld`.

Comment: It's log_slow_queries rather than log-slow-queries

Comment: Plus you have to create the log file manually before:
`sudo mkdir /var/log/mysql`
`sudo touch /var/log/mysql/slow-query.log`
`sudo chown -R _mysql /var/log/mysql/`

Comment: `log_slow_queries` was deprecated in MySQL 5.1.29 by `slow-query-log`.
The [MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-slow-queries) has more details.

Answer (score 19):

**Find log enabled or not?**

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%log%';
```

**Set the logs:-**

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON'; 

SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';
```

Answer (score 7):

[MySQL Manual - slow-query-log-file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log_file)

This claims that you can run the following to set the slow-log file (5.1.6 onwards):

```
set global slow_query_log_file = 'path';
```

The variable slow_query_log just controls whether it is enabled or not.

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem is making sure that MySQL server has the rights to the file and can edit it.

If you can get it to have access to the file, then you can try setting:
`SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 1;`

If not, you can always 'reload' the server after changing the configuration file. On linux its usually `/etc/init.d/mysql reload`

Comment: I get: ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'slow_query_log'

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Answer (score 6):

These work

```
SET GLOBAL LOG_SLOW_TIME = 1;
SET GLOBAL LOG_QUERIES_NOT_USING_INDEXES = ON;
```

Broken on my setup 5.1.42

```
SET GLOBAL LOG_SLOW_QUERIES = ON;
SET GLOBAL SLOW_QUERY_LOG = ON;
set @@global.log_slow_queries=1;
```

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32565

Looks like the best way to do this is set log_slow_time very high thus "turning off" the slow query log. Lower log_slow_time to enable it. Use the same trick (set to OFF) for log_queries_not_using_indexes.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to enable general error logs and slow query error log in the table instead of file

To start logging in table instead of file:

```
set global log_output = “TABLE”;
```

To enable general and slow query log:

```
set global general_log = 1;
set global slow_query_log = 1;
```

To view the logs:

```
select * from mysql.slow_log;
select * from mysql.general_log;
```

For more details visit this link

http://easysolutionweb.com/technology/mysql-server-logs/

Answer (score 1):

This should work on mysql > 5.5

> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%long%';
>
> SET GLOBAL long_query_time = 1;