# Slow query log in mysql

Tags: mysql

Can someone share how to enable slow query log (to see the slow queries) in Mysql 5 versions?

I need to analyse the slow queries, please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I enable MySQL's slow query log without restarting MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403793/how-can-i-enable-mysqls-slow-query-log-without-restarting-mysql)

Answer (score 4):

Begin by reading [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html).

## Edit

You can add one of the following lines in mysql server's configuration file:

```
log-slow-queries
log-slow-queries = /path/to/file
```

More recent versions of MySQL use these settings instead:

```
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /path/to/file
```

The slow query log file will contain the complete query text plus some additional information about the queries that take more then 10 seconds to execute. The 10 second threshold is configurable as well:

```
long_query_time = 10
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enable general error logs and slow query error log

To start logging in table instead of file

```
mysql > set global log_output = “TABLE”;
```

To enable general and slow query log

```
mysql > set global general_log = 1;
mysql > set global slow_query_log = 1;
```

Table name in which logging is done by default

```
mysql > select * from mysql.slow_log;
mysql > select * from mysql.general_log;
```

For more details visit this link

http://easysolutionweb.com/technology/mysql-server-logs/