# How can I turn on MySql Slow Queries in runtime?

Tags: mysql, logging, mysqldumpslow

Is there any way to turn Slow queries on when MySQL server in running? Because i cannot restart MySQL server since the manager in on vacation!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I enable MySQL's slow query log without restarting MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403793/how-can-i-enable-mysqls-slow-query-log-without-restarting-mysql)

Comment: This is mostly a guess backed only by reading docs, but using something like this might work: SET GLOBAL log_slow_queries = '/some/log/path', long_query_time = 1;

Comment: Thank you splitfeed. Why you just don't post an answer?

Comment: Did it actually work? I doubted it would since I haven't tried it myself

Comment: Variable 'log_slow_queries' is a read only variable. So out of luck. :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is mostly a guess backed only by reading docs, but using something like this might work

`SET GLOBAL log_slow_queries = '/some/log/path', long_query_time = 1;`

Comment: Thanks but i think `log_slow_queries` is a read-only variable in earlier MySQL versions.

Comment: the value of log_slow_queries is ON|OFF