# MySQL SELECT history

Tags: mysql

How can I keep a record of recent SELECTs performed on a table/DB? I am trying to fix an old codebase that runs very slow queries that are built in multiple nested functions. It would be much easier to just see what querys are being run then trying to follow the code when building them.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Slow Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html).

Comment: That involves restarting the MYSQL server to enable it, which is currently out of the question.

Comment: I don't think you'll find a solution that doesn't involve restarting the MySQL server.

Comment: @Juhana I thought maybe some type of trigger to log every `select`

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to restart mysql to enable this feature (slow query log).

See here : [How can I enable MySQL's slow query log without restarting MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403793/how-can-i-enable-mysqls-slow-query-log-without-restarting-mysql)

Comment: Thanks, but I am using MySQL 5.0.x