# How do I enable the MySQL slow query log?

Tags: mysql, sql

My MySQL version details are

1. Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
2. Software: MySQL
3. Software version: 5.0.96-community-log - MySQL Community Edition (GPL)
4. Protocol version: 10

How do I enable the MySQL slow query log?

Comment: @N.B. things are, if you make your google search nowadays, this question is the second result. The turns of life...

Answer (score 162):

***Version 5.1.6 and above:***

**1. Enter the MySQL shell and run the following command:**

`set global slow_query_log = 'ON';`

**2. Enable any other desired options. Here are some common examples:**

**Log details for queries expected to retrieve all rows instead of using an index:**

```
   set global log_queries_not_using_indexes = 'ON'
```

**Set the path to the slow query log:**

```
  set global slow_query_log_file ='/var/log/mysql/slow-query.log';
```

**Set the amount of time a query needs to run before being logged:**

```
   set global long_query_time = 20;
     (default is 10 seconds)
```

**3. Confirm the changes are active by entering the MySQL shell and running the following command:**

```
show variables like '%slow%';
```

***Versions below 5.1.6:***

1. Edit the /etc/my.cnf file with your favorite text editor
   vi /etc/my.cnf
2. Add the following line under the “[mysqld]” section. Feel free to update the path to the log file to whatever you want:

   `log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql/slow-query.log`

**3. Enable additional options as needed. Here are the same commonly used examples from above:**

**Set the amount of time a query needs to run before being logged:**

```
  `long_query_time=20
  (default is 10 seconds)`
```

**Log details for queries expected to retrieve all rows instead of using an index:**

```
 `log-queries-not-using-indexes`
```

**4. Restart the MySQL service:**

```
service mysqld restart
```

**5. Confirm the change is active by entering the MySQL shell and running the following:**

```
show variables like '%slow%';
```

**Update:1**

According to MySQL docs, the error #1193 occurs when you use wrong code for SQLSTATE.

```
Message: Unknown system variable %s
```

And, as you can see on the same page, the SQLSTATE 99003 is not defined.

refer this link:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: #1193 - Unknown system variable 'slow_query_log'

Comment: what to do above error is display while "set global slow_query_log = 'ON';"   command execute over phpmyadmin

Comment: @John, look at my update:1 answer.

Comment: When set the amount of time a query needs to run before being logged, if error occured:
ERROR 1232 (42000): Incorrect argument type to variable , use this instead : `set global long_query_time = 5;`

Comment: set global long_query_time = '20'; make error in mysql, don't quote the number please

Comment: Once you have it enabled, you'll quickly realize that it's really hard to read.  I made this to help me turn the MySQL slow query log into a couple of digestible spreadsheets: https://github.com/CherryCircle/MySQLSlowLogAnalyzer

Comment: Beware that restarting the MySQL service sometimes resets the variables.

Answer (score 8):

If your server is above 5.1.6 you can set the slow query log in the runtime itself. For which you have to execute this queries.

```
set global log_slow_queries = 1;
set global slow_query_log_file = <some file name>;
```

Or alternatively you can set the this options in the `my.cnf/my.ini` option files

```
log_slow_queries = 1; 
slow_query_log_file = <some file name>;
```

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log_file

Comment: Got error #1238 - Variable 'log_slow_queries' is a read only variable

Comment: Since MySQL version less that 5.1 check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403793/how-can-i-enable-mysqls-slow-query-log-without-restarting-mysql

Comment: Since 5.6.1, `log_sloq_queries` is replaced by `slow_query_log` -
 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log