# activate MySQL slow query log in MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

After trying to activate MySQL slow query mode provided by the user manual (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log_file) and other answers ([How do I enable the MySQL slow query log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609257/how-to-enable-mysql-slow-query-log)) , they all fail for different error messages:

```
(1)  mysql -h ${SERVER_NAME} -B -N -P ${PORT_NAME} -u ${USER_NAME} --password=${PASSWORD} -e "

    set global slow_query_log = 'ON';

    SET global slow_query_log_file=$HOME/slow-query-log-CLIENT-${CLIENT_ID}-YEARLY-${Local_time}.log;

    SELECT * FROM WHATEVER;"

ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 3: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

(2)  mysql -h ${SERVER_NAME} -B -N -P ${PORT_NAME} -u ${USER_NAME} --password=${PASSWORD} -e "

    set global slow_query_log = 'ON';

    SET global slow_query_log_file=$HOME/slow-query-log-CLIENT-${CLIENT_ID}-YEARLY-${Local_time}.log;

    SET global log_output=/home/user;

ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 3: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

(3) When I follow the MySQL user manual for the command line option, the following error message pops out:

```
mysql -h ${SERVER_NAME} -B -N -P ${PORT_NAME} -u ${USER_NAME} --password=${PASSWORD} -e --slow_query_log --slow_query_log_file=SLOW-CLIENT-${CLIENT_ID}-${Local_time} --global log_output=/home/user "

mysql: unknown variable 'slow_query_log_file='
```

Quite frustrating.  Could any guru enlighten?

Answer (score 0):

Since `SETs` will be lost if the server crashes, it is not practical to do it the way you describe.

Certain `SETs` need to be set by the privileged "root" user (or other user with `SUPER` privilege.

It would be better to do things this way:

Change the config file (possibly `/etc/my.cnf`) with

```
long_query_time = 1
slow_query_log = ON
slow_query_log_file = /usr/mysql/slow.log
```

(or pick some other *static* path and filename)

Then, to "cycle" the log, have a cron job

```
cd /usr/mysql
mv slow.log some-fabricated-name
mysql ... -e "flush logs"
```

Comment: Interesting idea!  About the cron job part, what does the "flush logs" mean?

Comment: Also, by following your settings in /etc/mysql/my.cnf, there is no more error message. However, there is no any slow.log generated for unknown reasons.  Could you enlighten?

Comment: You did restart `mysqld`?  `FLUSH LOGS` closes and reopens various log files; I think the slow log is included.  This, plus the `mv`, will effect the cycling.  Any relevant messages in mysqld.err or mysql.log?