# How to log mysql read next queries?

Tags: mysql, database, logging, netdata

I have a big load on my MySQL database.

With NetData ( https://github.com/firehol/netdata ), I saw that the handler "Read Next" sometimes jumps from 30-50 to 4M !

How can I log the concerned queries (**concerned by read-next jumps**), or detect what could cause this in any way ?

Thanks ahead

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403793/how-can-i-enable-mysqls-slow-query-log-without-restarting-mysql

Comment: Thanks but I'm already logging the slow-queries !

I just now to know which queries are using my RAM