# Is there a way to monitor my msql db requests

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

On my server the application that uses more CPU is MySQL database, my CPU peaks when I have many accesses to the DB, that's normal

what I want to do is to optimize accesses to DB

**is there any way to see which pages are most accessing the database?**

ps: I'm using `PHP 7.2.4`

Comment: Yes there is. It's called logging.

Comment: optimising your DB queries is a large topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I enable MySQL's slow query log without restarting MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403793/how-can-i-enable-mysqls-slow-query-log-without-restarting-mysql)