# Mysql stopped unexpecteadly on xampp

Tags: php, mysql, performance, xampp, innodb

I have production software with more than 50K row per table. It performs slow in insert and value retrieve. Table has already index. My Ram is 14GB and with Xenon processor.

If I increase `innodb_buffer_poll_size` 3G or more from my.ini file then mysql stopped unexpectedly.Whats the problem. What can i do now?

Comment: Have a look at the error log. A server won't just stop without logging something there

Comment: OK.can u suggest me how can i speed up my input and report show,there is around 15 users who given input using barcode.

Comment: So, what is the real question? How to speed up queries? Then look at the slow query log, or inspect long running queries using the execution plan. Or is the problem that your server crashes randomly from time to time (like you've asked)? Then look at the log to find the cause

Comment: I have a production software.if row increases 50K then slow down both value insert and value retrieve.There is around 15 users who give input.And there is minimum 30 users who continuously show report.Its installed on vmware.So that i increase innodb_buffer_poll_size from 16M to 2G.Because sometimes mysqld.exe service usage 100% cpu.So i want to increase innodb_buffer_poll_size.But if i increase it more than 2G then stooped mysql.My main problem is speed issue for both input and report showing.

Comment: And have you tried anything I suggested, like the slow query log, execution plans or the error log?

Comment: And, make sure your queries are optimised. The best configured server can't deal effectively with every badly written query that your developers throw at it.

Comment: @nico Hasse,ya am trying to do your suggestion.Now need to understand something

Comment: @MandyShaw working on query optimise,thanks.Need to understand more things.

Comment: Show us actual queries.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @RickJames this si on of my query,

Comment: $dt=date('Y-m-d');
    $sql=("SELECT Line FROM sewing_effi WHERE DT='$dt' ORDER BY Line ASC");
    $sql1=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    
    while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
     {
      
      $li=$row1['Line'];

Comment: $query=("SELECT 
        buyer.Buyer,ordr.ordr,ordr.Ship_Date,colour.Colour,sewing_effi.OP,sewing_effi.HEL,sewing_effi.Target,sewing_effi.TWH,sewing_effi.Line,sid_cutting_inventory.DT,
        SUM(cutting_inventory.qc_pass) AS Input,      
        SUM(sewing_output.QC_Pass) AS Toutput,
        SUM(sewing_output.Recieved) AS Recv
        FROM 
        cutting_inventory
        INNER JOIN sid_cutting_inventory ON
        cutting_inventory.SID=sid_cutting_inventory.SID
        LEFT JOIN
        buyer
        ON
        cutting_inventory.Buyer=buyer.CBuyer

Comment: LEFT JOIN
        ordr
        ON
        cutting_inventory.Buyer=ordr.CBuyer AND
        cutting_inventory.Ordr=ordr.COrdr
        INNER JOIN
        colour
        ON
        cutting_inventory.Buyer=colour.CBuyer AND
        cutting_inventory.Ordr=colour.COrdr AND
        cutting_inventory.Colour=colour.CColour
        LEFT JOIN sewing_output ON
        sewing_output.Barcode=cutting_inventory.Barcode

Comment: JOIN sewing_effi ON
        sewing_effi.Line=sid_cutting_inventory.Line
        WHERE sewing_effi.Line ='$li' AND sewing_effi.DT='$dt' AND ordr.Ship_Status='0' AND sid_cutting_inventory.Challan_Close_SS='0' AND sid_cutting_inventory.DT NOT BETWEEN  '2017-01-31 7:00:00' AND '2018-03-31 23:00:00'
        GROUP BY
        sewing_effi.Line,
        buyer.Buyer,
        ordr.ordr,colour.Colour
        ORDER BY sewing_effi.Line")

Comment: @RicJames ,Sorry for posting this way,because the query is too long.I saw another thing on task manager,my mysqld.exe usage 100% cpu

Comment: @NicoHaase can you tell how to create slow query log and how to see result?

Comment: Have you tried googling that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403793/how-can-i-enable-mysqls-slow-query-log-without-restarting-mysql might help

Answer (score 0):

**Do not use the mysql_* interface!**

```
        SELECT  Line
            FROM  sewing_effi
            WHERE  DT='$dt'
            ORDER BY  Line ASC"
```

What is the datatype of `DT`?  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`)

Assuming `DT` is a `DATE`, then you need `INDEX(DT, Line)` for extra efficiency.

For this:

```
        SELECT  buyer.Buyer,ordr.ordr,ordr.Ship_Date,colour.Colour,sewing_effi.OP,
                sewing_effi.HEL,sewing_effi.Target,sewing_effi.TWH,sewing_effi.Line,
                sid_cutting_inventory.DT,
                SUM(cutting_inventory.qc_pass) AS Input,
                SUM(sewing_output.QC_Pass) AS Toutput, SUM(sewing_output.Recieved) AS Recv
            FROM  cutting_inventory
            INNER JOIN  sid_cutting_inventory
                ON cutting_inventory.SID=sid_cutting_inventory.SID
            LEFT JOIN  buyer  ON cutting_inventory.Buyer=buyer.CBuyer
            LEFT JOIN  ordr  ON cutting_inventory.Buyer=ordr.CBuyer
              AND  cutting_inventory.Ordr=ordr.COrdr
            INNER JOIN  colour  ON cutting_inventory.Buyer=colour.CBuyer
              AND  cutting_inventory.Ordr=colour.COrdr
              AND  cutting_inventory.Colour=colour.CColour
            LEFT JOIN  sewing_output  ON sewing_output.Barcode=cutting_inventory.Barcode
            JOIN  sewing_effi  ON sewing_effi.Line=sid_cutting_inventory.Line
            WHERE  sewing_effi.Line ='$li'
              AND  sewing_effi.DT='$dt'
              AND  ordr.Ship_Status='0'
              AND  sid_cutting_inventory.Challan_Close_SS='0'
              AND  sid_cutting_inventory.DT NOT BETWEEN '2017-01-31  7:00:00'
                                                    AND '2018-03-31 23:00:00'
            GROUP BY  sewing_effi.Line, buyer.Buyer, ordr.ordr,colour.Colour
            ORDER BY  sewing_effi.Line"
                          )
```

I find it quite confusing to mix `LEFT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN`.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`  I'll make some guesses.

```
sewing_effi:  INDEX(Line, DT)  -- in either order
sid_cutting_inventory:  INDEX(Challan_Close_SS, DT) -- in this order
```

Do you have a 32-bit or a 64-bit version of MySQL installed?

Answer (score 0):

Installed 32 bit version mysql.I attaached some snapshot of tables and explain.I think it will be easy for you to detect my problem.
[Expalin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCFSE.jpg) [cutting_inventory table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrXC2.jpg) [sewing_effi table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paHGL.jpg) [sewing_output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zngZk.jpg) [sid_cutting_inventory table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDx3p.jpg)

*Challan_Receive_SSD and Challan_Close_SSD column store date
*Challan_Receive_SST and Challan_Close_SST column store time